# How to use like query with count value in mysql

Tags: mysql, count

I wish to use the count value of a table in the like search. How can i do? This is my query which shows #1111 - Invalid use of group function

```
  select driver_details.DriverId, 
           count(taxi_trip.AutoId) AS TotalTrip, 
           sum(taxi_trip.TripDistance) AS TotalTripDistance, 
           sum(taxi_trip.TotalFare) AS  TotalTripFare 
   from driver_details 
         left join taxi_trip 
          on taxi_trip.DriverId = driver_details.DriverId 
           and taxi_trip.PickupLAT != 0 
           and taxi_trip.DropLAT != 0 
           and taxi_trip.TotalFare != 0 
   where (date_format(taxi_trip.RequestDate,'%Y-%m-%d') >= 2015-07-17) 
     and (date_format(taxi_trip.RequestDate,'%Y-%m-%d') <= 2015-07-17) 
     and (driver_details.DriverId LIKE '%sa%' 
     or driver_details.Firstname LIKE '%sa%' 
     or driver_details.Lastname LIKE '%sa%' 
     or driver_details.TaxiPlateNo LIKE '%sa' 
     or count(taxi_trip.AutoId) LIKE '%sa%' 
     or sum(taxi_trip.TripDistance) LIKE '%sa%' 
     or sum(taxi_trip.TotalFare) LIKE '%sa%') 
   group by taxi_trip.AutoId
```

Comment: did you try with http://sqlfiddle.com ? You could provide us a sample fiddle there...

Comment: There also i got the same error message   Here is the error count(taxi_trip.AutoId) LIKE '%sa%' . Don't know how to use the count value in search

Comment: well, and what is the link...? btw, in your question you had an other error message...

Comment: In my opinion you should wrap this query to another one, but before make your agregation, and then use *LIKE* statement. You cant get this result with one Query. And Actually _count(taxi_trip.AutoId) LIKE '%sa%'_ this piece of code is your, Like works only with varchar not a numbers, and count works with numbers not a varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewriting it using **having**

```
select driver_details.DriverId, 
      count(taxi_trip.AutoId) AS TotalTrip, 
      sum(taxi_trip.TripDistance) AS TotalTripDistance, 
      sum(taxi_trip.TotalFare) AS  TotalTripFare 
from driver_details 
    left join taxi_trip 
     on taxi_trip.DriverId = driver_details.DriverId 
      and taxi_trip.PickupLAT != 0 
      and taxi_trip.DropLAT != 0 
      and taxi_trip.TotalFare != 0 
group by taxi_trip.AutoId 
having (date_format(taxi_trip.RequestDate,'%Y-%m-%d') >= 2015-07-17) 
  and (date_format(taxi_trip.RequestDate,'%Y-%m-%d') <= 2015-07-17) 
  and (driver_details.DriverId LIKE '%sa%' 
  or driver_details.Firstname LIKE '%sa%' 
  or driver_details.Lastname LIKE '%sa%' 
  or driver_details.TaxiPlateNo LIKE '%sa' 
  or count(taxi_trip.AutoId) LIKE '%sa%' 
  or sum(taxi_trip.TripDistance) LIKE '%sa%' 
  or sum(taxi_trip.TotalFare) LIKE '%sa%')
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, you want to use the value of

```
count(taxi_trip.AutoId)
```

as variable in your query as

```
'%sa%'
```

Try

```
DECLARE @taxiTrips INT;
SET @taxiTrips = SELECT count(taxi_trip.AutoId) FROM driver_details;
```

Then you can use `@taxiTrips` as variable.
So in your query change

```
driver_details.Firstname LIKE '%sa%'
```

to

```
driver_details.Firstname LIKE @taxiTrips
```

but i really dont know what you try to archive with this..

Comment: I wish to use in laravel 4.2